# Transparent faces in Edit Mode

Tags: modeling

I am not sure how it happened but all my faces are now semi-transparent in Edit Mode.

[image]

I have tried multiple settings to get solid faces back. I am not in wire frame mode and I made sure that "Limit selection to visible" is disabled as see in the picture. I have no idea why I can't get my solid faces back.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

BloodHound27

Comment: A possible cause may be the 3d viewport clipping parameters, give it a check. For a scene like this a default 0.1-1000 should works fine.

Comment: It turns out you were right @Carlo. If you re-post your comment as the answer, I will accept it as correct.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I think we'll mark this question as a duplicate for the sake of tidiness.

Answer (score 3):

Enable **limit selection to visible** [image]

Comment: The OP said that he tried that, and in his picture it is enabled.